# Resolution out stuck at 640x480 Win 7 on a Macbook Pro

Tags: windows-7, macos, multiple-monitors, resolution

Suddenly my display out is stuck at 640 X 480 resolution.

I'm running a Macbook Pro with Win 7 on the bootcamp side, using a minidisplayport on both. On the mac side everything works fine. On the Windows side, where it worked fine until two weeks ago, I can only extend or mirror at 640X480 when I plug in a VGA monitor (works fine through the MDP to HDMI cable). I've tried updating AND rolling back the drivers and using both the Windows and Nvidia control panels.

The graphics card is an Nvidia Geforce GT 330TM

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading you right, it still works with MDP to HDMI. Perhaps this isn't worth doing, but you could try doing a system restore to a point when the display was working properly.

You might also look into your boot options. I think this is in the `msconfig` tab for boot. Perhaps somehow the "base video" option got enabled. It limits you to 640-480 regardless of whether you have the right drivers installed.

Finally, you should be uber sure you actually do have the right drivers, and that they're not messed up somehow. There exists some decent third party software for scanning devices and downloading updated drivers for them. They might provide a fix, or at least certainty that you are indeed on an operable driver narrowing down the problem domain here.